# How to extract a url of a json file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want a extract a url from a json file and store that into the variable using the batch script.

Below is my json file.

```
 {
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/releases/v1.0.0",
  "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets",
  "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets{?name,label}",
  "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tarball/v1.0.0",
  "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/zipball/v1.0.0",
  "id": 1,
  "node_id": "MDc6UmVsZWFzZTE=",
  "tag_name": "v1.0.0",
  "target_commitish": "master",
 }
```

I want the line between `"upload_url"` and `{?name,label}"` stored into the variable. which is

```
https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets
```

Can I get the batch script command for achieving this?

I tried the below command:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%# in (' type tmpCurl.json^|find /i "upload_url"') do echo %%#
```

but it give this much output:

```
"https
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you require:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('type tmpCurl.json ^| findstr /i "upload_url"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims={" %%i in (%%b) do set "result=%%i"
)
echo %result%
```

The first loop splits the string on `:` delimeter and assigns everything before `:` on to metavariable `%%a` leaving you with everything below assigned to `%%b`

```
https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets{?name,label}",
```

The second loop splits the string `%%b` on `{` and assigns everything before `{` to `%%i` leaving us with:

```
https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets
```

Comment: Now the output is `https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets{?name,label}","upload_url":"https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases
/1/assets`
I want `https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets`

Can you please help me to get that?

Comment: The very latest code is what I wanted. Thanks a lot. Also can you please put the explainaton as well?

Comment: Explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your provided `.json` content something like this may be sufficient for your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=3Delims^={^"^  %%A In ('Find "upload_url"^<"tmpCurl.json"')Do @Set "UURL=%%A"
@Set UURL 2>Nul&Pause
```

*Where the second line is there just to show you the saved variable with its value.*

Answer (score 0):

Your sample Json is invalid due to the trailing comma in the 2nd last line.
Better use Json tools/script languages which can handle Json.

A PowerShell one liner wrapped in batch

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\05\18\SO_56197577.cmd
@Echo off
For /f "Usebackq delims=" %%U in (`powershell -NoP -C ^
  "(Get-Content tmpCurl.json | ConvertFrom-Json).upload_url.split('{')[0]"
`) Do Set "upload_url=%%U"
set upload_url
```

Sample output

```
> Q:\Test\2019\05\18\SO_56197577.cmd
upload_url=https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets
```